# How to trigger a Form from a Macro and get the inputs from a Form into VBA Module Code

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a macro where I would like to create Custom Buttons to the Message Box, and I thought of triggering a form that looks like a Msgbox with options like "YTD", "Specific Months". Here's the below form I have created:

[image]

And the code inside the form is as below:

```
Option Explicit
Public InputMsg As String

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
InputMsg = "YTD"

End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
InputMsg = "Specific Months"
```

I would like to get these Input Values to the Module Code which I mentioned below:

```
Sub Chts_Functions_UB()

'CallingForms
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set WsCharts = Wb.Sheets("Trend Charts")
Set UBMainChart = WsCharts.ChartObjects("UBMainChart")
Set UBMonthlyYTDSht = Wb.Worksheets("UM - Monthly & YTD")
Set FPFAChart = WsCharts.ChartObjects("FP_FA_YTD Chart")
Set FPBPChart = WsCharts.ChartObjects("FP_BP_YTD Chart")
Set FPRMDChart = WsCharts.ChartObjects("FP_RMD_YTD Chart")
Set FPMonthlyYTDSht = Wb.Worksheets("FP - Monthly & YTD")
YearValue = WsCharts.Range("A1").Value
'btnFunctionName = WsCharts.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
WsCharts.Range("F2").Value = btnFunctionName

Dim Crows As Long, Ccols As Long
Dim NamedRng As Variant
'****Here I would like to get the Input from the Form (YTD or Specific Months Button)***
Crows = UBMonthlyYTDSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Ccols = UBMonthlyYTDSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
On Error GoTo 0
```

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the public variables until and unless it is absolutely necessary. Pass the relevant value as a parameter as shown below.

**Your form code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Chts_Functions_UB "YTD"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Chts_Functions_UB "Specific Months"
End Sub
```

**Your module code**

```
Sub Chts_Functions_UB(ChartType As String)
    '
    ' Chts_Functions_UB code here
    '
End Sub
```

Also avoid the use of `On Error Resume Next`. Use it judiciously and use proper error handling. For example

```
Sub Chts_Functions_UB(ChartType As String)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    '
    ' Chts_Functions_UB code here
    '
    
LetsContinue:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**Note**: `LetsContinue` and `Whoa` are names that I like to use. You can give them names that you like.

Comment: Do I need to give separate codes for each Button Selection Like "YTD" & "Specific Functions" in the Module code? or do I need to use some IF condition to get the String correct?

Comment: How did you plan to use `InputMsg` in your original code?

Comment: I would like to take that as String, like If InputMsg is "YTD" go with this process and if it is "Specific Functions", it has to go with other procedure.

Comment: I just got this!! Thank you... let me try whether it's working perfectly working or not!! :)

Comment: `If ChartType = "YTD" Then` similarly `ElseIf ChartType = "Specific Months" Then`